# Add a native dll (Gmsh4-7.dll) to a dotnet framework project

Tags: c#, native, mesh, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I have a .Net project. For the meshing issue I use a .Net wrapper for Gmsh 4.7.1.
If I use .Net standard the native dll will be loaded.
But if I use .Net framework, the error is "dll could not be loaded".
I checked all native dependencies. All of them are System32 dlls.
Are there any ways that I reference this native dll to my .Net framework project?
Many thanks

Comment: 32 or 64 bit? Does your dll match your app's "bit-iness"?

Comment: native dll is 64 bit. my project is 64 bit too.

Comment: Did you copy the .dll to your project's `bin` folder?

Comment: Yes, I did. but did not work.